# How to make ExpressJS listen on a domain

Tags: javascript, express, dns, listen

How do I make ExpressJS listen on domain, I recently got a domain and I want Express.JS to listen on that domain without any ports. How do I do that. If express can't do that could you tell me a package that do it? Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to add your current research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...and I want Express.JS to listen on that domain without any ports.

You always have to listen on a port. The default port for HTTP (for instance, when you go to `http://example.com`) is port 80 (for HTTPS it's 443). Those are the standard ports web servers listen on.

So assuming you're running your ExpressJS code on a server at the IP address that the domain name resolves to, you just use the standard ExpressJS code for listening for HTTP requests. Here's their ["Hello World" example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html), modified to use port 80 (and semicolons):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 80; // <===

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I've tried your code but it says the that the port is already used... BTW, I'm using a VPS

Comment: @WALNUTZGAMING - That means...the port is already used. :-) You probably have a web server like Apache or Nginx installed and running. You'll either replace that with your ExpressJS (e.g., Node.js) server process, or (more likely) want to configure your web server to be a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) for your ExpressJS server.